# Prepending a tab URL to a defined URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This question pertains to a chrome extension Browser Action:

I was wondering if someone could help me out with this quick issue.  I want to know how to prepend a URL to the current URL using javascript.

For example the following will get the URL of the tab one is on using certain chrome functions...

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
});
```

but I want to prepend a URL so that the output looks something like this (e.g. if they were on google.com)

> http://www.foo.com/index.php?bar=http://www.google.com

The following is my failed attempt at doing this...

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = "http://www.foo.com/index.php?bar=" . tab.url;
});
```

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**

The code above injects the URL result into the tags...

```
<p id="currentLink">Loading ...</p>
```

but how can I also get this to show up as the image src for the following...

```
<img id="currentLink">
```

Another script turns this link into a specific image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `.` for concatenation? Use `+` instead:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = "http://www.foo.com/index.php?bar=" + tab.url;
});
```

Comment: I am so used to using PHP that I completely forgot about that.  However if you don't mind me asking a related follow up question... I forgot to add that to the end of this question and will do so in a minute.

Comment: @user2284703: Are both elements in the same document?

Comment: yes but despite the fact that i used the same id in the question... I am using two different IDs in the script. "currentLink2"

Comment: -1 to the question: it's not a related question. Please make a new question and delete this "extra" part from this one, and I'll be happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: why would oyu downvote this if I have already chosen a best answer?